# What are free RS-232 terminal programs?

Tags: windows, usb, terminal-emulator

I've read signals from an AVR in university, but I forgot what software I was using. I can't seem to find any on Google. Maybe I am not looking right.

What are some free UART software for AVRs? I know there is HyperTerminal but it doesn't work well on Windows 8 - I think.

Comment: HyperTerminal has some 'interesting features' that makes it unfit for use with this kind of projects. For example it silently filters some character combinations. If memory serves me well, you can't eg. reset a modem using ATZ through hyperterm. If there is one such 'feature' then there is no guarantee that it is the only one. I personally prefer PuTTY like in one of the answers below.

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend either [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) or [Hercules](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html) as free serial terminal programs.

Comment: Important to get your software from the actual project home page. The only correct URL for PuTTY is http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/ Don't use software download sites like softonic, softpedia, tucows, ... where the source of the software is unknown and cannot be verified. The putty.org website is *not* owned by the PuTTY author and therefore cannot be trusted.

Comment: Hercules is the best I tried so far. @bitsmack Consider including links to the software you mentioned.

Answer (score 11):

Realterm works well. Teraterm too. Both are free and open-source.

In the future, you want to search for "[Terminal Emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator)" programs, and you'll find plenty of results.

Comment: I'll second the recommendation for Tera Term.

Answer (score 3):

I also like "terminal", which has some nifty features like macros and data graphing.  With it's unfortunate name, its hard to search for -- https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/