# Terminal emulator software with a "playback" option

Tags: windows, windows-7, terminal-emulator

I currently use **PuTTY** or **TeraTerm** to communicate with an embedded dev system via UART. On the embedded system we implemented a simple command terminal with a 1-line history, which works great.

The problem is that many time our tests consist of repeating sequences of commands. Thus, I need to re-type the sequence for every test run.

I saved the sequence in a text file and use the mouse to select-copy-paste commands into the terminal window. I cannot select multiple lines because the system is not fast enough and any command past the first one is lost.

This becomes very tedious very fast. So, I am looking for a terminal emulator program that allows me to "replay" a saved macro in the form of a text file, possibly controlling the input rate, or adding short "pause" commands in the playback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing the site, I found [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3230/31151) answer pointing to the **[Terminal](https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/)** terminal emulator. This program happens to have support for macros, and even to *Pascal*-based scripting, which could work fine for me. Its drawbacks is that I could not find way to change the terminal window's font to a fixed-width font, and that the auto-scroll feature does not work.

Then, while playing with **TeraTerm**'s settings, I found out that it is possible to set the Serial Port's character delay and line delay (menu `Setup` -> `Serial prot...`). It is also possible to set the line delay explicitly for the Copy & Paste action (menu `Setup` -> `Additional settings...` -> `Copy and Paste`).

So I set the line delay to 2000 msec and now I can paste a sequence of commands, having ample of time for each to process and finish, such that no commands get lost.